# Calculating discriminant of elements of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, integer-rings

Could someone please guide me through this one?

Let $a$ be a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^3+rx+s \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Calculate: $disc(1,a,a^2)$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What definition of the discriminant are you using? Probably it is some determinant, which you can expand. It also equals the discriminant ${\rm disc}(f)$ of your polynomial $f$. It also equals $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)} N(f'(a))$ where $n$ is the degree of $f$ and $N$ is the norm.

Comment: I'll soon upload a fuller answer